# Resizing activities from other apps or adding a view of another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-windowmanager

I have been using android's window manager to addviews to the screen and putting the activity to the back so it looks like the activity is run on a floating window drawn over other apps , 
by simply inflating the view and using          `windowmanager.addView(view,   windowParameters)`
now what I would like to know is if it would be possible to do this on a view from another app or is it possible to run an activity from another app in mine.

Also could it be possible to resize a view of another app ?

Any doucumentation, example or reference is appreciated.

The question might not be very clear , excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The reason is security and privacy.

Your app is running in one or more processes that have a specific user-id. Other apps are running in their own processes, each of which has a specific user-id. The underlying operating system prevents code in one process from accessing memory in another process. Because of this, you cannot get a reference to a `Window` or a `View` in another application.